# Laravel 5.1.4 unexpected 'Route' after fresh install

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5, wamp, laravel-routing

I just installed laravel 5.1.4 locally under blabla.dev I have also another practice project locally and now both projects cant be accessed and i get this error:

FatalErrorException in routes.php line 14: syntax error, unexpected 'Route' (T_STRING)

anyone had this issue?

I am on a windows environment, wamp, the basics are installed, composer, node. everything was working great until i installed this second projects.

i added a virtual host in apache v hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\lara-practice\public"
ServerName lara.dev
<Directory "C:\wamp\www\lara-practice\public">
AllowOverride All
Require local
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\larasilos\laravel\public"
ServerName larasilos.dev
<Directory "C:\wamp\www\larasilos\laravel\public">
AllowOverride All
Require local
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

these are the 2 projects and i also have this added to my hosts file:

127.0.0.1 lara.dev 
127.0.0.1 larasilos.dev

thats about it, anyone any ides?

Comment: Please post line 14 (and maybe a few around that mark) of your routes.php

Comment: it is a fresh install of laravel, nothing is touched of the code.
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

what is interesting, as i said, is that now both my projects dont work anymore...

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when I had copied some code sent over a chat. The issue for me was with a funky character showing up between the end of my code on a line and the comment following it. Not sure if the character was introduced by the chat tool (HipChat) or because code was sent from a Mac and to a PC (Win 10). Couldn't detect the character in sublime text... however when I manually deleted each space/tab and then re-formatted the code, it worked. I know this is a very late answer, but just in case someone else runs into this.